# Re-adding SQL Server 2K5 cluster services

Tags: sql-server-2005, service, windows-cluster

We've previously installed MS SQL Server 2005 in a fail-over cluster environment on two servers. After a major failure this weekend, the whole cluster has been recreated, but all the services are missing.

Does anyone know exactly what services I need to re-add in order to get MS SQL Server 2005 to be failover clustered again? I've taken a look at the services list, but there are too many services that I know -did not- belong in the cluster administrator.

Answer (score 1):

The only services which need to be clustered on the MSSQLSERVER and the SQLSERVERAGENT.  The resource group will need to have all the drives, the SQL Server Network Name and the IP Address added to it with the correct dependencies set.

Comment: I was under the impression there was some kind of Analysis service as well?

Comment: It would seem I need to make a reinstallation when the services has gone away :-/